# Load model from variable

Tags: javascript, three.js

All the advices about loading Three.js model into scene involve `JSONLoader`:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var createMesh = function(geometry) { 
   var zmesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );
   zmesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
   zmesh.scale.set( 3, 3, 3 );
   zmesh.overdraw = true;
   scene.add(zmesh);
};
loader.load("the_model.js", createMesh);
```

But what if I want to use a JavaScript file already loaded whth a `<script>` tag?

```
var the_model = {
   "metadata" : {
      "formatVersion" : 3.1,
      .......................
   },
   "scale" : 1.000000,
   "materials" : [ {
   ........................
}
```

How can I use this `var the_model` with Three.js?

Putting it instead of geometry didn't help.

Comment: What format is your model in?

Comment: @Alex Wayne: I do not know the format name. I've converted this JSON from OBJ using a Python script included with Three.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a pattern like the following:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var model = loader.parse( the_model );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( model.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
scene.add( mesh );
```

If your add a material into your model, you would do something like this:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( model.geometry, materials[ 0 ] );
```

three.js r.58

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using [`THREE.JSONLoader.parse`](http://threejs.org/docs/58/#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader) instead of [`THREE.JSONLoader.load`](http://threejs.org/docs/58/#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader):

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var geometry = loader.parse(the_model);
createMesh(geometry);
```

Since an AJAX request doesn't have to be made, the call is synchronous.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use synchronous calls. Imagine loading several models; Your interface will freeze.

Comment: @gaitat: the file with model is already loaded using the `script` tag. If you are caring about slow model parsing - JavaScript isn't asynchronous in that meaning.